# Using Word add-in JavaScript API in Word Online (browser)

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, add-in, office365, office-js

I am trying to use the [Word add-in JavaScript API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt616496.aspx) in Word Online (browser)

when I run

```
Word.run(function (context) {
  // Create a proxy object for the document.
  var thisDocument = context.document;
})
```

It runs fine in Word 2016 desktop but in Word Online I get an error:

*'Word' is undefined*

Questions:

1. Is this Word Api usable in Word Online?
2. If not, when will this Api be usable in Word Online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the new Word APIs are not yet available on Word Online. As shown on [this site](https://dev.office.com/blogs/Office-js-Public-Preview), they should be available on Word Online in Q1 of 2016.

Gabriel Royer

Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: Thanks.  Will all the functionality in the Word API be implemented in Word Online in the Q1 release?  Or just a subset?

Comment: This is so dumb... why does `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.3)` return `true`, if Word online obviously does not support it? And by the way, broken link.